# How to add colorbar to DICOM pyplot.pcolormesh plot? (Python)

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization, colorbar

After importing and `matplotlib.pyplot.pcolormesh` the CT image [as instructed by somada141 four years ago](https://pyscience.wordpress.com/2014/09/08/dicom-in-python-importing-medical-image-data-into-numpy-with-pydicom-and-vtk/), how do you add a color bar to the resulting greyscale image to estimate its numerical values? Or, is there a better way to report this data (i.e. a better way to quantify this visualization to attach a number to the color)?

Comment: You produce a colorbar via `pyplot.colorbar()`. I think you need to go much more in detail what the problem is or in how far `colorbar` would not work for you.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest That was astounding easy, thank you! I was expecting much more coming from MATLAB -- namely, grabbing figure and axes handles and writing a function to analyze the plotted data, and that's what I was seeing from answers to similar questions. Could you also tell me how to update the colorbar's values after zooming in on the plotted image? I am using Spyder 3.2.8 within the Anaconda distribution (Anaconda Navigator 1.8.7).

Comment: Not sure I understand the issue. If you zoom, the values on the colorbar should not change, because zooming does neither change the data nor the mapping from data to color.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Yes, that's why I'm wanting to update the colorbar -- not expecting to do so automatically -- to reflect only the values visible after zooming-in. The goal is to share only the figure (without Spyder zoom in-zoom out feature) with a third party so the colorbar reports the values they're actually seeing with the highest resolution possible.

Comment: So you want to update the image's colors *and* the colorbar?